# SUMIFS function excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need a formula to sum the values in a range of cells if the content in another range of cells equals the text currently in a cell in a completely separate table.

For example,

sum the values for D7:D999 
If the text in G7:G999 equals the text in `'sheet2'!B9` (a completely different cell in another sheet)

Note: The text in cell B9 changes which is why I can't just write the text in B9 in the function.

I tried the following formula, but it didn't work:

```
SUMIFS(D7:D999,G7:G999,"=INDIRECT('sheet2'!B9)"
```

Comment: Try this array formula and check if this works for you. =SUM(IF(G7:G999=Sheet2!B9,D7:D999,0))  Press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER to create array formula from within the formula bar. Now the formula shall be wrapped in curly braces. You need not refer text in B9 in your formula but you can certainly refer B9 as cell reference in the formula.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Once I've created an array formula by pressing CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER, how do I refer B9 as cell reference in the formula? Also, how do I expand the formula to include more criteria for summing D7:D999?

Comment: Perhaps can you show some sample data in your question so as  to get an idea of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Ok, I have a table with which I track my expenses. Column F states if the entry is an income or expense, column E states what currency the entry is in and column G the category. In addition to the criteria of column G for which you've already help me, id like to add more criteria. Sum column D if column f = expense, if column e = dollars, and if column g equals b9 (as you've explained earlier)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my understanding of your question. I believe a simple SUMIF that you tried earlier but without INDIRECT should work.

I have this sample table D1:G11. B15 holds the formula for SUMIF and B9 in sheet2 has the required text to be compared with CAtegory in Sheet1 Col G.

Formula in B15

```
=SUMIFS(D2:D11,E2:E11,"=USD",F2:F11,"=Income",G2:G11,Sheet2!B9)
```

You do not need INDIRECT here. A simple SUMIFS should work as seen below. This example assumes that you want to Sum where Currency is USD & it's 'Income' category and cells in G match Sheet2!B9. You can build similar SUMIFS based on your expected criteria.

Please confirm if this works for you. Alternatively you can add a sample data in your question and provide further clarity as to why you need INDIRECT.

[image]